# File splitting to different files

Tags: unix, teradata, informatica-powercenter

I have a file which has data in the below format

```
Col1
1,a,b,c
1,e,f,g,h,j
2,r,t,y,u,i.o
2,q,s,d,f
3,q,a,s,l
4,r,y,u,p,o
4,o,l,j,f,c,g,b,c
4,d,f,q,
.
.
.
97,w,e,r
3,f,g
100,q,a,x,c
```

Now I want to split this file to 100 different files so that each file has data based on first column . Example - First file should have only data which has value 1 in first column and second file should have data which starts with 2 in second column and so on till 100 files .

Please tell me the approaches in Informatica, Unix or teradata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use Transaction control transformation to get multiple files generated with respect to column value.

```
Take a variable port 
V_curr - Col1
V_prev - Col1
V_flag = IIF(V_curr = V_prev,0,1)

Now import transaction control transformation and pass the pipeline.
In properties, Transaction Control Condition type,
IIF(V_flag =0, TC_COMMIT_BEFORE, TC_CONTINUE_TRANSACTION)
```

Once you execute the workflow, multiple files will be generated with respect to Col1.

For ref - https://kb.informatica.com/h2l/HowTo%20Library/1/0114-GeneratingMultipleTargetsFromOneTargetDefinition.pdf

Also check - https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

seems simple enough... use filename port on the flat file target and have an expression transformation with port filename_out dynamically created as a derivative of the first column value e.g. "FileOut" || Port1 || ".dat"

Then connect output port of filename_out to input port of filename on the target

Comment: This will create only files with the file names . How to load the data inside the file ?

Comment: So long as you send the rest of the ports to your target, the name of the file they get loaded to will be determined by the filename port. From the sample records provided it appears that you only have 1 column, this being the case you could use INSTR (see example of how to use this function here  https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/informaticareference.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/instr/amp/ ) to return the position of the first comma then feed the result into a LEFT function to extract just the number. If there is more to this question please specify it

Comment: Result files should not just contain only the number port . It should contain entire row . So for the File 1 it should have all the rows which starts with 1 in that above table. Likewise 2,3 till 100 .

Comment: Daniel's advice is actually what you need. Create this new port to use as filename, connect the full row to target row - and that's it. This is exactly what you need. Or... you might need to sort the data first to make sure all rows come together.

Comment: See http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/02/dynamic-flat-file-generation-in_10.html?m=1. Try scenario 4, test it and come back with the exact error you get when trying (if any).